# Is there a way to process point in area faster in Python? shapely implementation

Tags: python, coordinates, shapely

I have attempted to try in Python the same thing I achieve in a GIS Software.

I have 51 centroids to compare to 90,000+ parcels and find the overlap.

It seems that my script is working (which I am happy to have been able and write) but I was curious if there is a way to speed this up? it takes around 5mins. I appreciate any help I can get as the final scope would be to process way more centroids and way more parcels so I am concerned by the time it would take.

I added the code below as well as a few lines of how the csv and json files look.

````
import json, csv, time
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

start = time.time()

with open('M035TaxPar_CY20_FY20.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            #print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            my_coord = tuple([float(row[10]), float(row[11])])
            my_coord = Point(my_coord)
            line_count += 1
            
            with open('boston_parcels_all.json', 'r') as f:
                array = json.load(f)
                
            dict_size = len(array.get("features"))
            for i in range(0, dict_size -1):
                sub_dict = array.get("features")[i] 
                geometry_dict = sub_dict.get("geometry")
                current_Pol = geometry_dict.get("coordinates")
                
                attribute_data = sub_dict.get("properties")
                parcel_id = attribute_data.get("MAP_PAR_ID")
                
                try:
                    final_Pol = Polygon(current_Pol[0])
                except AttributeError:
                    continue
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                if not my_coord.within(final_Pol):
                    continue
                else:
                    if parcel_id == None:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print(f"My pol: {parcel_id}, my point: {row[0]}")
                
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
end = time.time()
total_time = end - start
print("\n"+ str(total_time))```

CSV file:

MAP_PAR_ID,LOC_ID,POLY_TYPE,MAP_NO,SOURCE,PLAN_ID,LAST_EDIT,BND_CHK,NO_MATCH,TOWN_ID,X_coord,Y_coord
0301290001,F_772282_2959076,FEE,3,ASSESS,,20191107,,N,35,-71.07030535235137,42.36703589444949
0301286000,F_772818_2959719,FEE,3,ASSESS,,20191107,,N,35,-71.0682938996932,42.36876187375208


JSON file:

{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "M035TaxPar_CY20_FY20",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ -71.074767681, 42.3489358757 ],
                        [ -71.0745071763, 42.3490067112 ],
                        [ -71.074852421, 42.3497214512 ],
                        [ -71.0757149372, 42.3494869825 ],
                        [ -71.0753495281, 42.3487373608 ],
                        [ -71.074767681, 42.3489358757 ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "SHAPE_Leng" : 324.191190544,
                "SHAPE_Area" : 6483.24124923,
                "MAP_PAR_ID" : "0401134000",
                "LOC_ID" : "F_771022_2952578",
                "POLY_TYPE" : "FEE",
                "MAP_NO" : "4",
                "SOURCE" : "ASSESS",
                "LAST_EDIT" : 20191107,
                "NO_MATCH" : "N",
                "TOWN_ID" : 35
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [ -71.0554563931, 42.3547109221 ],
                        [ -71.0550339868, 42.3548837812 ],
                        [ -71.0557334699, 42.3555313301 ],
                        [ -71.0564003565, 42.3554356917 ],
                        [ -71.0562325294, 42.3545663782 ],
                        [ -71.0554563931, 42.3547109221 ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "SHAPE_Leng" : 351.344209198,
                "SHAPE_Area" : 7627.60108948,
                "MAP_PAR_ID" : "0304410000",
                "LOC_ID" : "F_776224_2954721",
                "POLY_TYPE" : "FEE",
                "MAP_NO" : "3",
                "SOURCE" : "ASSESS",
                "LAST_EDIT" : 20191107,
                "NO_MATCH" : "N",
                "TOWN_ID" : 35
            }
        }
    ]
}
````

Comment: You're building all parcels over and over for each point you're investigating. That can't be fast.

Comment: Have you considered using geopandas? This can be done very quickly with geopandas.sjoin

Comment: @AKX thanks - I was fairly sure that something is not efficient in the code.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado - that was the next (planned) attempt after shapely. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your GeoJSON file only once, not for each point you read from the CSV.

You can also use `csv.DictReader` to make your code a bit shorter.

```
import json, csv, time
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon


def parse_parcel(feature: dict):
    geometry_dict = feature["geometry"]
    coordinates = geometry_dict["coordinates"]
    attribute_data = feature["properties"]
    parcel_id = attribute_data.get("MAP_PAR_ID")
    if not parcel_id:
        raise ValueError("Parcel ID is missing")
    pol = Polygon(coordinates[0])
    return (parcel_id, pol)


def read_parcels():
    with open("boston_parcels_all.json", "r") as f:
        geojson = json.load(f)
    assert geojson["type"] == "FeatureCollection"

    for sub_dict in geojson["features"]:
        try:
            yield parse_parcel(sub_dict)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Error parsing geometry {sub_dict}: {exc}")


def main():
    start = time.time()
    parcels = dict(read_parcels())
    print(f"Read {len(parcels)} parcels.")
    with open("M035TaxPar_CY20_FY20.csv") as csv_file:
        for line_count, row in enumerate(csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=","), 1):
            my_coord = Point((float(row["X_coord"]), float(row["Y_coord"])))
            for parcel_id, parcel in parcels.items():
                if my_coord.within(parcel):
                    print(f"Parcel ID: {parcel_id} contains {row[0]}")

    print(f"Processed {line_count} records.")

    end = time.time()
    total_time = end - start
    print(f"Total time: {total_time:.3f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thank you, @AKX 
This is indeed next level - running this I get a full screen output of coordinates, the read count and then KeyError: 0 for line 37 in main and line 47 in module.
I'll try to understand the flow/logic. Goal would be to print only the matched ones (line 38). 

Really appreciate you taking time to point out the issue.

Comment: found the issue
print(f"Parcel ID: {parcel_id} contains {row[0]}")

row is now a dictionary and not a list. So I replaced row[0] with row.get("MAP_PAR_ID").
Any idea why it prints it "ï»¿MAP_PAR_ID" ? not sure why it sees those weird characters.

Many thanks - from 4 minutes to 10 seconds.

Comment: The weird column name is because your file has a BOM marker at the start - change the encoding parameter when you open the file accordingly.

Comment: Also yeah, my bad with the `row[0]`. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in pandas+geopandas should be as simple as:

```py
import pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd

df = pd.read_csv('M035TaxPar_CY20_FY20.csv')   
shp = gpd.read_file(
    'boston_parcels_all.json', engine='GeoJSON'
)
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gpd.points_from_xy(df.X_coord, df.Y_coord)
)
joined = points.sjoin(shp, predicate='within')
```

See the geopandas docs on [spatial joins](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, Michael
Absolutely, looks much more clean and easy to follow. WIll surely run this one too as it helps mastering more ways of reaching the same goal.

Thank you for taking the time to offer this version too.